# Del-key deletes whole treeview, when the shortcut is re-defined dynamically

Tags: delphi, treeview, shortcut, vcl

I have following code:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
var
  m: TMenuItem;
begin
  // Here, some dynamic stuff is done, so every node gets individual items in the mainmenu
  Node1.Clear;

  m := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  m.Caption := 'Delete';
  m.ShortCut := VK_DELETE;
  m.OnClick := AcDelete;
  Node1.Add(m);
end;

procedure TForm1.AcDelete(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(TreeView1.Selected) then Exit;
  TreeView1.Selected.Delete;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  // Only when I do this, the "Del"-key-loop will break. But then, the new
  // selected item won't get new menu individual items.
  // TreeView1.OnChange := nil;
end;
```

At the form there is a `TMainMenu` and a `TTreeView` .

Whenever something is selected in the treeview, an individual menu will be created for each node. This created menu usually includes "Delete node" which has the shortcut [Del]. However, this must be dynamically created too.

When I press the [Del] key, the item gets deleted by `AcDelete` and the follower node will be selected of course. Due to the selection of the follower node, `TreeView1Change` gets invoked which creates a new individual menu. It is all fine until then.

**The problem is**, that the VCL still thinks that the [DEL] key is pressed, so the follower node will be deleted too. And its follower too. And so on, until the whole list is empty. So, deleting one item with the [Del] key deletes everything. This does not happen when I use the mouse, of course.

What can I do to tell the VCL that the [Del] key is not pressed anymore, when the new menu is created? Some workaround I could do in `TreeView1Deletion`?

---

The DFM code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 192
  Top = 107
  Width = 1305
  Height = 750
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object TreeView1: TTreeView
    Left = 128
    Top = 56
    Width = 233
    Height = 193
    Indent = 19
    TabOrder = 0
    OnChange = TreeView1Change
    OnDeletion = TreeView1Deletion
    Items.Data = {
      04000000220000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000
      09323334323334323334210000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000
      0000000000000832336173647361641F0000000000000000000000FFFFFFFFFF
      FFFFFF0000000000000000067274656574721E0000000000000000000000FFFF
      FFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000053333333333}
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 88
    Top = 80
    object Node1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Node'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably such behavior happens because you are creating new items with same shortcut before processing of the shortcut is done. Just do it as TLama suggested, it should solve the problem and it is much cleaner.

Comment: @TLama It is the only approach I can do. The node classes are providing an interface which outputs all "actions" which can be done to the node. The nodes itself will decide what can be done to them, so the menu will be built dynamically. Also the delete action will have code which is specific to the specific node class. Therefore, my GUI does not know how to handle the node.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've deleted my comment due to a minor mistake I've claimed there. But an action is the way to go. You don't need to bother with building menu. You can have a menu item binded to an action to which you set `Visible` to False and the binded menu item disappear and *suppress* the shortcut as well. When you select a certain node, you'll show or hide actions that you want.

Comment: I know how actions work. But I require that the node class defines all actions which can be done. And since the code will be extended by different node types, I don't want to hard-code everything in the form.

Comment: @rinntech If you create one TAction with shorcut=vk_delete, then instead of assigning m.OnClick and m.ShortCut you can assign m.Action and m.Action.OnExecute. It is almost same code as you have, but you always will have only one item (TAction) with shortcut vk_delete. I think it will be enough to solve the problem. But suggestion of TLama is better (if you know all possible actions for different nodes).

Comment: @rinntech, sorry, but I missed your point. All what you'd do is setting e.g. `DeleteNodesAction.Visible := YourConditionToAllowDeletion;` from the `OnChange` event of the tree. That's all. Then if you'll have that action binded to more controls, all disappear. You're currently adding that menu item always, which always keeps the shortcut active. You must add it only when the node can be deleted, or am I missing the point of this question ?

Comment: But the delete even should always be enabled. I can't put the delete action in an action list, since every node-class can have a different "Delete" action (or some special node types even no delete action), with different code, so I need to re-create the "Delete" menu-item everytime a new node is selected. I do understand that the re-creation of the "Delete" menu item will re-trigger the pressed key. I need to find a workaround to break the re-triggering of the key.

Comment: There are couple of approaches. One is to use `TActionList` and use `OnUpdate` of every item to set it's `Visible` and/or Enabled` property according to desired conditions. If you're using `TPopupMenu`, you can use `OnPopup` to set individual item's visibility and/or availability. `Node` class should have boolean properties which define which actions are applicable and then use those properties in `OnUpdate`/`OnPopup` event handler.

Comment: I got your problem wrong. Well yes, that menu item recreation is the source of the problem. But why to do it ? Even if you were having several node classes and for each you'd have a separate `AcDelete` like method (which would be very impractical), you could just assign such method to `OnClick` for the still existing menu item. And if the node class wouldn't provide deletion, the menu item would just be hidden.

Comment: What does `Node1.Add(m)` do?

Comment: @David, `Node1` is a parent menu item into which is added the newly created menu subitem `m`.

Comment: Oh, I see. That info is in the .dfm.

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 action DeleteAction: TAction with shortcut assigned (DEL). Change code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
var
  m: TMenuItem;
begin
  // Here, some dynamic stuff is done, so every node gets individual items in the mainmenu
  Node1.Clear;

  m := TMenuItem.Create(Self);
  m.Caption := 'Delete';
  m.Action := DeleteAction;
  DeleteAction.OnExecute := AcDelete;
  Node1.Add(m);
end;

procedure TForm1.AcDelete(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Assigned(TreeView1.Selected) then Exit;
  TreeView1.Selected.Delete;
end;

procedure TForm1.TreeView1Deletion(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  // Only when I do this, the "Del"-key-loop will break. But then, the new
  // selected item won't get new menu individual items.
  // TreeView1.OnChange := nil;
end;
```

It should help (because we don't create items with same shortcut in run-time anymore).